# django sites and showing id in admin editor

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the `Site` module in django.  In the admin interface, I see domain name and display name.  I'd really like to see the primary key id, as well, however, since I specify the sites by `SITE_ID`.

Now I could do this by editing `./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/admin.py`, but that's poor form in so many ways.  I'd just add "id", thus:

```
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'domain', 'name')
    search_fields = ('id', 'domain', 'name')
```

I did the following in one of my `models.py` files, which helps in the shell but doesn't show up in admin:

```
def site_name(self):
    return '{domain} ({id})'.format(
        domain=self.domain, id=self.id)

Site.__str__ = site_name
```

Any suggestion how to do this (or pointer on what I'm doing wrong that I think I want it)?

Answer (score 2):

In your admin.py, add this code:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'domain', 'name')
    search_fields = ('id', 'domain', 'name')


admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)
```

Since `Site` is already registered in admin, you will have to `unregister` is first, then register it again.

Comment: Thanks, that looks quite promising.  But it appears that the pip installed version is loaded after my code: I get a warning that the class can't be unregistered, then that it is already registered.